# Replace inverse function

Tags: functions, replacement

I'm solving an expression like so:

```
Solve[u[x] == u[a] + u[b], x]
```

Mathematica returns

```
{{x->(u^(-1))[u[a]+u[b]]}}
```

If I now specify the function `u` more precisely, via

```
% /. {u[x_] -> x}
```

what I get is

```
{{x->(u^(-1))[a+b]}}
```

i.e. Mathematica replaces the function but not its inverse. Is there any way of replacing the inverse appropriately as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace function `u` with your definition, not only the `u[x]` symbol. Defining `u` as a function solves the problem

```
Solve[u[x] == u[a] + u[b], x] /. {u -> Function[x, x]}
(* ==>  {{x -> a + b}} *)
```